# Non-differentiability of $\max \limits_i f(i)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How can we formally show that $\max$ and $\min$ functions are non-differentiable?

In particular, I was looking at the L1 matrix norm defined as:

$\|A\|_1 = \max \limits_{i \le j \le n} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{m} |a_{ij}|$

Surely, because of the absolute values in the definition it won't be differentiable. However, in general, how could we should non-differentiability of $\max \limits_i f(i)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that as long as the maximum **exists** your function is identical to a constant function on that interval. That is suppose;

$ f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R $ and given an interval $I$ (due to some bound on $f$) $ \max \{f(x) \ | \ x \in I\} $ exists and is equal to $c$. So the function we wish to differentiate is in fact the maximum function. So all we wish to do is to calculate teh derivative of

$ f: I \to \Bbb R $ given by $f(x) = c$ which is nothing but a constant and is sure as the sun and moon differentiable on the interval $I$. But again the maximum or the supremum as some wish to call it must exist.

---

This was a discussion on real functions. And I believe you are talking about differentiating on $\Bbb R$, the definition of which (including limits) does not accept matrices in its domain. Unless of course you are talking about something I have not learnt about. Hope I helped.

Comment: Good point about max being equivalent to a constant function. Thanks!